# Call Django view to update model data upon row button click in HTML

Tags: jquery, python, html, django, django-models

I am currently new to Django & Web development.

I have displayed some data in HTML template. Data is in table row format. User can edit the data (from Text and Drop down menu) from each row . I want to call django view to update that row data in corresponding model database upon Button click associated to that row.

Here is my HTML Code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Candidate Name </th>
        <th>Change Application Status </th>
        <th>Submit </th>
    </tr>
    {% for eachApplication in myCompanyApplications %}
        <td>
            <a href="/candidate/{{ eachApplication.candidateId }}/">{{  eachApplication.candidateName }}</a></td>
        <td>
            <select>
                {% for choice in list.currentApplicationStatus %}
                    <option {{choice.0}}>{{choice}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="submit" class="btn" value="Commit" name="mybtn"></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

I want to detect changes `(applicationStatus change etc)`

Clicking a button should call a view and that view will make changes in corresponding `Django model`

If there is any better approach please mention.

*Any help will be really appreciated.*

*Thanks :)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. put your 1st for loop tds in a form
2. give every form a dynamic id like form-{{
   eachApplication.candidateId }}
3. Use ajax to post data to your view on form submit,

something like this might help you:

```
$('body').on('submit',"#formid",function(event) {
             event.preventDefault();
             url = 'your  django view url '
             $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url,
                    data: $(this).serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
                    success: function(data){
                        //do something on successs
                    }
                    },
                    error:function(data){
                        //do something on error
                    }
                  });
         });
```

Comment: Better if you use class for targeting form

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will try to add this & get back if stuck somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function  () {
$('#my-form').submit(function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'your View URL',
        type: 'form method (POST,GET,HEAD,......)',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {
            'Value':$('#input').val(),
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken':$("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val(),

        },
        success:onSuccess,
    });
    function onSuccess (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        //do something on successs
    };

});
```

});

And u can add an error function as u like :D